# Htaccess URL Rewriting [GET doesn't works]

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my site I use "show.php?cat=1" type URLs. I want to change for SEO optimization this link types.

I have tried before but I can't understand how to do that.

```
# Root Host
-- Project Folder
--- index.php
--- show.php
--- css/js/ and other folders
```

My first purpose is change my links

```
show.php?cat=1 to show/1/
```

my code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/show/(.*)$ show.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesn't work. I have a *GET* error. What's wrong?

**And my css files gone to /show/css URL**

I'am very angry, my css files gone but Get function doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Edit: If I change show code to 'test' like that, page becomes 404. Why? 
Note: I'am using WAMP Server 3, Apache Rewrite_module is working.

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ show.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*"The requested URL /project1/test/1 was not found on this server."*

Comment: Take a look at the contents of $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST. Is the parameter in there at all?

Comment: @Scovetta There was no problem about parameters, i checked all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ show.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Without first `/` in htaccess RewriteRule pattern

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know how can I except css files in this rewrite rule. Do you know?

Comment: Use absolute links for css or add `<base href="/">` in html head.